# Causal relationship with deal (Bayes-network)

Tags: r, classification, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I am working with multiple binary vectors e.g., A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H.
I want to find the classification between them.  I have tried the following:

```
 log_data<-read.csv(choose.files(), as.is = T, header = T, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
 data<-log_data[2:ncol(log_data)]
 data
 TIME  A B C D E F G
 1     1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
 2     0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
 3     1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
 4     1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
 .....................
 fit <- network(data)
 fit.prior <- jointprior(fit)
 fit <- getnetwork(learn(fit,rats,fit.prior))
 **Error in postc0c(node$condposterior[[1]]$mu, node$condposterior[[1]]$tau,  : 
 NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)**
```

Getting this error just because all are continuous variable and NULL at mu.

How should I proceed in order to classify after creating a network?